# Is "like" here a conjunction or a preposition?

Tags: conjunctions

> I'm sure you have heard something like, "You can do anything you want."

Is "like" a conjunction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorities differ as to whether it's a conjunction or preposition when used in that sort of way, but it's certainly one or the other. Cambridge dictionary online just says that both that sense, and the one closest to it, are both preposition and conjunction. The structure of the sentence makes it hard to say for sure in which way it is acting.